# DCE RPC bink_nak reason protocol version not supported

Tags: linux, windows, rpc, dce

I have an application hosted on Linux 5.5 that uses SMB and RPC calls to a Windows server to gain some data from the registry.

The problem is that when I have a look at the wireshark traces I see a response coming from the windows server stating that bind_nak reason protocol version not supported. I see that the Linux server is using Major version 5 and minor version 0. Tried with Windows 2008 server. Same problem seen. Due to this I am not able to get the data I want.

Any idea how I could decode the problem? What do I look for on the windows/linux server.

Note: - The initial to and fro using SMB protocol is successful. That is I can see in the wireshark traces that there was a negotiation of protocol, then I can see commands such as session setup andx request, session setup andx response, NT create andx request, NT create andx response etc etc.